# How to make an image resize in a responsive design that has a z-index applied?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have an image that has a zindex applied to it. I would like to the image to resize as the browser gets narrower. Since the image is about 250 pixels wide (much smaller than the browser window), the image doesn't resize till the browser window is narrower than 250px.

I know that is the normal way it should happen, but I would like the image to scale relative to the browsers width meaning that if the browser window is 1000 pixels wide and the image is 250 pixels wide then if the browser window is reduced to 750 pixels then the image becomes 188 pixels wide (a relative shrinking). Is this possible to accomplish in CSS?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what difference the z-index makes, but have you tried setting the width of the image to 25%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you do!

Just use percentage instead of pixels to define the width.

But, if the image is inside of an selector that has the width defined in pixels, not in percentage, it may not work properly.